# count number of characters of a particular field in a databse

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The below shows my table **users** and some entries in the table. In users table  `phoneid` is stored in particular manner as shown below .Some values are above 16 and some others are below 16 .

I want to display `phoneid` into two categories (One is above 16 & another one is below 16).
How can I categorize it into two category ???

```
    phoneid 

    43f46cc43f4c797c
    03C03372-B549-4FA2-9A6B-E28F250E8DWE
    4f7e35b38470abd0
    74C03372-B549-4FA2-9A6B-E28F250E8EBA
    bbc4fe41d79aa730
    61152d549ba924fa
    c3ac44f7c0cd2a62
    03C03372-B549-4FA2-9A6B-E28F250E8DWE
    d07e063ef6d4598e
    2f3467d189e6a8ac
    fc35ee8d18f03b9e
    189cc387b2b3ce3f
    84B03372-B549-4BN2-9A6B-E28F250E8OPJ
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just to list the users and order them according to their length 
you can simply run

```
 SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY length(phoneid);
```

but if you need to get for example the ones with length greater than 16 just do this :

```
 SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE length(phoneid) > 16;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use.. `strlen()` function of php..

which will return the `character count of a string..`

like

`echo strlen($phoneid);`

Answer (score 0):

The [length function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) in MySQL can take care of that.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE LENGTH(phoneid) > 16;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName GROUP BY length(phoneid);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to display phoneid into two categories (One is above 16 & another one is below 16). How can I categorize it into two category ???*

You can add temp field to your result sets, as below, to show the phone ids as defined categories based on their char lengths.

```
Select *, 
       case when char_length( phoneid ) <= 16 then 
                 phoneid else '' end as 'Phone_Category_1',
       case when char_length( phoneid ) >  16 then 
                 phoneid else '' end as 'Phone_Category_2'
From   users
```

**Sample Result would be**: (rest of the columns not shown here):

```
phoneid                                Phone_Category_1  Phone_Category_2
43f46cc43f4c797c                       43f46cc43f4c797c
03C03372-B549-4FA2-9A6B-E28F250E8DWE                     03C03372-B549-4FA2-9A6B-E28F250E8DWE
4f7e35b38470abd0                       4f7e35b38470abd0
74C03372-B549-4FA2-9A6B-E28F250E8EBA                     74C03372-B549-4FA2-9A6B-E28F250E8EBA
```

You can omit `phoneid` from result set and can depend on `phone_category_1` and `phone_category_2`.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable comments .its very helpful.because this code is very new for me .